How to get the location from network-circular data
I dont get it, i read in some articles and forums about the location api in order to get the location from network-circular data with low accoracy 20m-300m, i also asked chatgpt and told me to use low accuracy in the geolocator but when i do this it does not work :
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Geolocation Example',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  String _locationMessage = "Press button to get location";

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _checkPermissions();
  }

  Future<void> _checkPermissions() async {
    var status = await Permission.location.status;
    if (!status.isGranted) {
      await Permission.location.request();
    }
  }

  Future<void> _getLocation() async {
    try {
      await _checkPermissions();
      Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
          desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.low,
          forceAndroidLocationManager: true,
);
      setState(() {
        _locationMessage =
            "Lat: ${position.latitude}, Lon: ${position.longitude}";
      });
    } catch (e) {
      if (e is PermissionDeniedException) {
        setState(() {
          _locationMessage = "Location permission denied.";
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          _locationMessage = "Error: ${e.toString()}";
        });
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Flutter Geolocation Example'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              _locationMessage,
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _getLocation,
              child: Text('Get Location'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
  }
}

Did i understand anything wrong here?
